# Angular Filter and Merge Array of Objects

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have:

**arrayBefore**

```
arrayBefore = [{name:'n1', items: [i1]}, {name:'n2', items: [i2]}, {name:'n1', items: [i3]}]
```

I want to create a function:

**myFunction**

```
myFunction(arrayBefore)
```

So it will produce:

**arrayAfter**

```
arrayAfter = [{name:'n1', items: [i1, i3]}, {name:'n2', items: [i2]}]
```

I have tried to implement myFunction using map() and filter(), but I can't get it working correctly. I would show some code I tried if I had the idea I was getting close, unfortunatly this is not the case. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reduce` method is what you are looking for:

```
const result = arr.reduce((a, {name, items})=>{
     a[name] = a[name] || { name, items:[] };
     a[name].items.push(...items)
     return a;
 }, {});
```

An example:

```js
let arr = [
    { name: 'n1', items: ['i1'] },
    { name: 'n2', items: ['i2'] },
    { name: 'n1', items: ['i3'] }
];

const result = arr.reduce((a, {name, items})=>{
     a[name] = a[name] || { name, items:[] };
     a[name].items.push(...items)
     return a;
 }, {});
 
 console.log(Object.values(result))
```

Comment: It took me some time to understand what is going on. But it works perfect!

Comment: @NielsFerguson I am glad to help you!:)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the `groupBy` operation. It's not doable by only `map` and `filter`. You need a `reduce`. See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: It seems like the example was indeed the solution. I accepted the answer from @StepUp because it was the first correct one to come in.